# How can I simplify this hideous query?

Tags: mysql

I've gotten to the point with this query where it's become too unwieldy to modify and I'm sure it's also become rather inefficient.

I have a table of items which may have any variable number of properties so these properties are listed in small tables ... item id and property id usually make up the index, and the property tables will have additional information.  In essence they're used for filtering a huge number of items to at least the relevant subset.

```
SELECT * FROM item
INNER JOIN itemwearTable 
ON (id=itemwearTable.itemID AND itemwearTable.wearlocID=1)
WHERE item.id IN (
 SELECT id FROM item
 LEFT JOIN itemalignTable 
 ON item.id=itemalignTable.itemID
 WHERE
   itemalignTable.itemID IS NULL OR
  (itemalignTable.itemID=item.id AND itemalignTable.alignID=1)
)
AND 
item.id IN (
 SELECT id FROM item
 LEFT JOIN itemgenderTable 
 ON itemgenderTable.itemID=item.id
 WHERE
  itemgenderTable.itemID IS NULL OR
  (itemgenderTable.itemID=item.id AND itemgenderTable.genderID=1)
)
AND
(item.id IN (
 SELECT id FROM item
 LEFT JOIN itemgenreTable 
 ON item.id=itemgenreTable.itemid
 WHERE
  itemgenreTable.itemid IS NULL OR
  (itemgenreTable.itemID=item.id AND itemgenreTable.genreID=1)
)
OR
item.id IN (
  SELECT id from item
  LEFT JOIN itemclassTable 
  ON item.id=itemclassTable.itemid
  WHERE
   itemclassTable.itemid IS NULL OR
  (itemclassTable.itemID=item.id AND itemclassTable.classID=1)
))
AND 
item.id IN (
 SELECT id from item
 LEFT JOIN itemlocTable ON
  item.id=itemlocTable.itemid
  WHERE
   itemlocTable.itemid IS NULL OR
   (itemlocTable.itemID=item.id AND itemlocTable.locID=1)
)
AND
item.minlvl <= 50
ORDER BY item.sdesc
```

Note I've used =1 here in many places to replace the php variables that would normally be part of the script generating the query.  The problem is that while these items are used to narrow the results, I have another table itemaffTable that has additional data (amount for example) which matches on item.id=itemaffTable.itemID  but I can't seem to see how to get that inserted without seriously messing up what's already there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Stephen. Is it entirely necessary in your subqueries to include "itemgenreTable.itemID=item.id"? Is this the same as your left join criteria? Actually, it seems your where clause can simply be "itemgenreTable.genreID=1" because itemgenreTable.itemID will either be null or equal to the item.id as per your join. EDIT - Oh, I see it's genre in one and gender in another, but I think the principle still applies.

Comment: Zec, I'm really not sure if it's necessary to be perfectly honest.  I will try to simplify while I await further insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*, iwt.* FROM item i
INNER JOIN itemwearTable iwt ON i.id=iwt.itemID 
LEFT JOIN itemalignTable iat ON i.id = iat.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemgenderTable igt ON i.id = igt.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemgenreTable igrt ON i.id = igrt.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemclassTable ict ON i.id = ict.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemlocTable ilt ON i.id = ilt.itemID
WHERE (iat.itemID IS NULL OR iat.alignID = 1)
AND (igt.itemID IS NULL OR igt.genderID = 1)
AND (igrt.itemID IS NULL OR igrt.genreID = 1)
AND (ict.itemID IS NULL OR ict.classID = 1)
AND (ilt.itemID IS NULL OR ilt.locID = 1)
AND i.minlvl <= 50
AND iwt.wearlocID=1
ORDER BY i.sdesc
```

Comment: The ORDER BY should be i.sdesc and the iw.* should be iwt.* but otherwise WOW.  What a stunning decrease in the amount of code.

Comment: I've decided my second version isn't right, it wasn't doing anything useful with the LEFT JOINs.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess my test data didn't reveal the problem but tomorrow... oh tomorrow ... :-)\

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT item.*, itemwearTable.* FROM item
INNER JOIN itemwearTable
  ON (id=itemwearTable.itemID AND itemwearTable.wearlocID=1)
LEFT JOIN itemalignTable
  ON item.id=itemalignTable.itemID
LEFT JOIN itemgenderTable
  ON itemgenderTable.itemID=item.id
LEFT JOIN itemgenreTable
  ON item.id=itemgenreTable.itemid
LEFT JOIN itemclassTable
  ON item.id=itemclassTable.itemid
LEFT JOIN itemlocTable
  ON item.id=itemlocTable.itemid
WHERE (itemalignTable.itemID IS NULL OR itemalignTable.alignID=1)
  AND (itemgenderTable.itemID IS NULL OR itemgenderTable.genderID=1)
  AND (itemlocTable.itemid IS NULL OR itemlocTable.locID=1)
  AND ((itemgenreTable.itemid IS NULL OR itemgenreTable.genreID=1)
      OR (itemclassTable.itemid IS NULL OR itemclassTable.classID=1))
  AND item.minlvl <= 50
ORDER BY item.sdesc
```